# Open Workbook on new instance

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on my code that open workbooks, i want it to open workbooks in a new instance, will this work? It's opening the workbook, but how can I check if it's open in a new instance?

```
Sub AQUAS()
 Dim bookPath As String, bookWb As Workbook
 bookPath = "\\C:\FLUXO CAIXA HINDY - 118.xlsm"
 Dim Result As VbMsgBoxResult
 Dim NewExcel As Object
 Set NewExcel = New Excel.Application
 
 With NewExcel
 
 If Dir(bookPath) = "" Then MsgBox "Spreadsheet not found": Exit Sub
 
 If IsWorkBookOpen(bookPath) Then
        Result = MsgBox("File in Use, Open read-only?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "AQUAS")
        If Result = vbYes Then
            Workbooks.Open (bookPath), True, True
            Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
 Else
        Workbooks.Open (bookPath), True
        Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
 End If
 
 End With
 
End Sub
```

Comment: While you're investigating (learning about) this new Excel instance business, you should make the instance visible so you can better understand what is happening and have control over the open instances. Right below `With NewExcel`. use the line `.Visible = True`. The usual purpose of using it (not visible), is to perform operations that the user should not be aware of i.e. open a workbook, perform the operations, (save) and close the workbook and quit the instance as if nothing ever happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work.

However, you are opening the Workbook not in the new created instance. The `With`-clause tells VBA to use the object (in your case the new Excel Instance) for all members that are preceded with a dot. So to open the Workbook in that newly created instance, use

```
With NewExcel
    If Dir(bookPath) = "" Then 
        MsgBox "Planilha não encontrada"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If IsWorkBookOpen(bookPath) Then
        Resultado = MsgBox("Arquivo em Uso, Abrir somente leitura?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "AQUAS")
        If Resultado <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
      
       .Workbooks.Open bookPath, True, True
    Else
       .Workbooks.Open bookPath, True
    End If
    .Application.Visible = True
    .Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
 End With
```

Be careful, your code will not be able to close that Excel instance.

Easiest way to check that you created a second instance is to use the task manager: You should see two Excel instances. To prove that the Workbook was opened with that new instance, kill one of the Excel sessions (of course you should save your work):

*Either* you killed the original instance (where the code lives), then the Workbook holding the code is now closed but the opened Excel Workbook (FLUXO CAIXA HINDY - 118.xlsm) is still open,
*Or* you killed the new Session, FLUXO is gone but the Workbook with the code is still open.

Just for curiosity: What is the reason that you want to create a second instance?

And a remark: It is nice to translate at least the relevant terms of your code like *"Arquivo em Uso, Abrir somente leitura"* so that someone not able to understand Portuguese don't have to guess what is going on.

Comment: Since `NewExcel` is the application object, you should use just `.WindowState...` (it possibly won't work if the application object is not visible). I think it is kind of mandatory to set the application object to be visible (`.Visible = True`) since there is no line of code that quits it. The warning after the code seems kind of insufficient.

Comment: I intend to open it in a new instance to get around the lags and stutters, some workbooks are very large, so when I'm working on several they tend to take a long time to process codes, formulas and everything.

Comment: Add  the statement  `.Application.Visible = True`, that did the trick for me. If it doesn't help, comment out  `.Application.WindowState = xlMaximized` and retry.

Comment: Worked, thanks! Thanks againd for the modifications on my original code